# What's the point of premium ammo for SU-26?

Tags: world-of-tanks

As I look at params of premium ammo for it seems it's only worse than standard.

[image]

```
                     Standard: Premium:
       Penetration:  60-100    56-94 (Worse!)
       Damage:       83-138    83-138 (same)
       Caliber:      76        76
       Splash:       0         0
```

Is there some hidden parameter that makes it better? Range? Trajectory? Travel time? Or is it simply an omission of the authors?
Is there any point to buy it ever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Penetration values for AP shells are for 0-100m.  After 100m, the penetration falls off.  Penetration values for HEAT (and HE) shells are true any range.  At longer ranges (>300m), you are actually getting a higher effective penetration.  SPGs like the SU-26 are often firing at these longer ranges.

Note that HEAT and HE shells are not normalized like AP/APCR shells, so HEAT and HE are less effective against angled or sloped armor.

See https://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Battle_Mechanics#Penetration_Mechanics and https://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Ammo for references.

Comment: While this is correct, the actual stats on the prem ammo still seem like a mistake. We dont know the exact penetration loss over distance on the AP shell, but I would assume the difference on actual penetration is so small that it doesnt warrant these stats.

Comment: It is definitely a little odd now that I look at things more closely.  Using some assumptions, I come up with a break-even point  between AP and HEAT at about 300m.  I'm going to revise my phrasing above.

Comment: @Granger44 Normalization is not related to bounces. These are different things

Comment: I was referring to the ricochet mechanics and not bounces.  From the wiki: "If the normalized impact angle of an AP or APCR shell on the target's armour exceeds 70° (80° for HEAT), a ricochet (a specific variant of a bounce) occurs...."  In other words, it uses the angle after normalization to determine if a ricochet happens.  Granted, I should have said "angled and sloped armor".  However, normalization also decreases the effective armor by moving the impact angle closer to 90°, so it should also affect bounces to some degree.

Comment: HE shells doesn't bounce so angled/sloped armor does not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would like to correct some errors in the previous answers:

> Note that HEAT and HE shells are not normalized like AP/APCR shells,
>   so HEAT and HE are less effective against angled or sloped armor.

This is true for **HEAT** but **HE** shells can't be bounced thus normalization wouldn't make a difference. Please note that it is possible that you hit with a **HE** shell for no damage but it does not mean that it is a bounce.

If you check on [tanks.gg](http://tanks.gg/en/wot/su-26#tab:details.eq:Aq00000) you will see that there is no difference in soft stats between **AP** and **HEAT** shells. The only difference is the **HEAT** shells have less penetration than the **AP** shells.

Please note that using **HEAT** is less effective since the **HEAT** nerfs and this is especially true for arty because the accuracy of arties is abysmal and you can easily end up hitting the tracks.

You should use **HE** in most cases when you play arty and only use **AP** in some special situations where you know that you will probably be able to hit your target.

So to answer your question: there is no point in buying **HEAT** for your tank.

Comment: ...so, back to the original question, is there any point to pay the gold for HEAT?

Comment: Added a conclusion to my answer.

Answer (score -2):

HE shells can still do damge if you don't penetrate. It also has a greater chance to cause module/crew damage.

In general it's better to use AP rounds, but if you manage to sneak behind a target and shoot at their backs (where armour rating is usually lower than even the most modest of HE rounds), you can do more good with HE rounds. Just remember to switch back to AP as the target will most likely start to turn back towards you :P

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer too the question as the HE ammo available for this thank is not premium, the question is about the premium ammo verses the non-premium.

Comment: ...also, good luck sneaking behind a target with artillery.

Comment: Meh I always get thrown off by the name  with "HE" in it... Was thinking HESH. Anyway, HEAT is supposed to be higher pen than AP with AP-like damage. So not sure why this tank has weird HEAT shells